# Pass Parameter to Window after Application.Run

Tags: c#, wpf

I can start WPF windows with my WindowController class in order to be able to call them up via Com, for example. This works quite well with the following code.

```
ComWindow comWindow = new ComWindow();
Application App = new Application();
App.Run(comWindow);
comWindow.DataContext.MyParameter = 5; //This line is only called after the window is closed.
```

However, I would now like to be able to address the open window from outside (e.g. change parameters, call methods). So far I have not found a functioning possibility. App.Run starts a message loop and thus blocks further processing of the code. Is there a way to access the running application or the window started in it?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Move that line before `App.Run()`?

Comment: Try `new ComWindow() { DataContext.MyParameter = 5 };`

Comment: Not really, it is not a WPF application but a class library. I therefore have no App.xaml, ... and no Main method available.

Comment: Creating an application in a class library seem quite odd, what if there is already one created in your appdomain? What is the actual goal of all this? How is the library meant to interact with the user of said library?

Comment: @Marius: This only works at the start of the form. However, I would like to be able to change the parameter later. This does not work then.

Comment: @JonasH: I need this to be able to make WPF forms available to an old VFP programme via COM. I use App.Run instead of Window.ShowDialog because the windows often refer to Application.Current.